# Boostrap Search Bar - How to remove space between form elements in boostrap grid

Tags: html, css

Here is a horizontal search box - with 3 elements

made using boostrap grid

How to remove the gaps between elements
I tried **width:100%,**
its not filling the column.

```
<span class="row">


            <span class="col-md-3 col1">

                <button type="button" class="btn btnLocation" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">

                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Location <span class="caret"></span>

                              </button>

                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                  <li> <a href="#">a</a> </li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">b</a> </li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">c</a> </li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">d</a> </li>
                                  <li class="spanider" role="seperate"></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">e </a></li>


                              </ul>
            </span>

             <span class="col-md-6 col2">
               <input type="text" class="inpSearch form-control" id="search-church" placeholder="Your location (City, State, ZIP)">
            </span>





            <span class="col-md-3 col3">
                 <button class="btnLocation btn" type="submit">Search.....</button>

            </span>


        </span>
```

How to remove the gap between the elements.

[image]
[image]

Fiddle:
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/djsreeraj/hn9kz647/2/)

Comment: You can remove the padding on both right and left side. E.g. `padding-right: 0`

Comment: Check this out [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LorekB/Lmp44xfs/4)

Comment: @LorekBryanson Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your css

```
.row > span {
   padding: 0;
}
```

this will remove all gaps/spacing between your elements.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your html file as :

```
<span class="row">
  <span class="col-md-3 col1 padding0">
    <button type="button" class="btn btnLocation" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Location <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li> <a href="#">a</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">b</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">c</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">d</a> </li>
      <li class="spanider" role="seperate"></li>
      <li><a href="#">e </a></li>
    </ul>
  </span>

  <span class="col-md-6 col2 padding0">
    <input type="text" class="inpSearch form-control" id="search-church" placeholder="Your location (City, State, ZIP)">
  </span>
  <span class="col-md-3 col3 padding0">
    <button class="btnLocation btn" type="submit">Search.....</button>
  </span>
</span>
```

And edit css file by addding :

```
.padding0{
  padding:0
}
```